# How can I add default value in input in the dynamic template-driven forms

Tags: angular, angular6

Below is the sample of **template driven form** in **angular 6** which is dynamic and it could be any number of form. So I don't want to create and use variable in class something like `[(ngModel)]="anyVariable"`. If I write `value="Rakesh"` in the form then it is not showing.

So, How can I set default value of `firstName` and `lastName` input?

```
<form #paxForm="ngForm" name="passengerForm" novalidate>

    <label>First name*</label>
    <input type="text" value="Rakesh" name="firstName" ngModel/>

    <label>Last name*</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="lastName" ngModel required/>

    <label>Mobile number*</label>
    <input type="tel" name="mobileNumber" value="" ngModel required/>

    <input type="button" value="Submit" (click)="submitPaxForm(paxForm)"/>
</form>
```

**Return Value:**

```
paxForm:{
    value:{
        mobileNumber: "97987987",
        firstName: "rakesh",
        lastName: "pal"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you make a stackblitz with your example ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" ngModel="Rakesh"/>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-53517039

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this by relay on two way data binding so it's easy for me to get all forms values

consider this example

*AppComponent*

```
  formsValues=[
    {
        mobileNumber: "97987987",
        firstName: "rakesh",
        lastName: "pal"
    } , 
    {
        mobileNumber: "2233556",
        firstName: "sam",
        lastName: "well"
    }
  ]
```

*Template*

```
<div *ngFor="let frm of  formsValues" class="form">
    <label>First name*</label>
    <input type="text" value="Rakesh" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="frm.firstName"/>

    <label>Last name*</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="frm.lastName" required/>

    <label>Mobile number*</label>
    <input type="tel" name="mobileNumber" value="" [(ngModel)]="frm.mobileNumber" required/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" (click)="submitPaxForm(frm)"/>
</div>
```

[**demo stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53517039)

> but I think reactive form array is much better for your case

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
Got it fixed by directly aasigning the default value to ngModel.

Example:

```
'<form  #userData="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getData(userData.value)">
     <div class="fields">
     <label>Building</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id='building' 
     name='building' ngModel='1234'>
     <label>Floor</label><input class="form-control" type='text' id='floor' 
     name='floor' ngModel='2'>
     </div>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>'
```